# C# classes for creating DocuSign Envelope using REST

Tags: docusignapi

I was wondering if there was sample base classes for creating an Envelope using the REST API for DocuSign.

What we are trying to accomplish is to be able to instantiate and Envelope object and add the necessary templates and document to it kind of like you do with SOAP but using the REST API.

I could try to copy the JSON sample that they have on the DocuSign Documentation and convert those to classes and go from there but was wondering if there is a more complete sample out there as we'll need to pull templates, modify the values on the tabs and combine templates with documents before sending the Envelope for signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Answer with all of the currently offered **[REST DocuSign SDK's](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools)**

- [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-csharp-client)
- [Java SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-java-client)
- [PHP
  SDK](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client)
- [Node
  SDK](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-Node-Client)
- [Python
  SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client)
- [Ruby
  SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client)
- [Objective C
  SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-objc-client)